# Return json response instead of list of Django models

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

I am new to python and Django, this is my first project. I followed a tutorial which returned a list of objects. I want to return json instead.

I have tried JsonResponse, json.dump but I don't think im implementing these right

```
class ListVenuesView(generics.ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = VenueSerialiser

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = (Venue.objects.all())
        location = self.request.query_params.get('location', None)
        latitude = location.split('S')[0]
        longitude = location.split('S')[1]
        venue_gaps = {}
        for venue in queryset.iterator():
            locationArray = [y.strip() for y in venue.postcode.split(',')]
            distance = gmaps.distance_matrix([str(latitude) + " " + str(longitude)], [str(locationArray[0]) + " " + str(locationArray[1])], mode='driving')['rows'][0]['elements'][0]
            m = distance["distance"]["value"]
            venue_gaps[m] = model_to_dict(venue)
        sorted_venues = dict(sorted(venue_gaps.items()))
        #print(sorted_venues)
        jsonResponse = json.dumps(venue_gaps, sort_keys=True)
        print(jsonResponse)

        return JsonResponse({'data':jsonResponse}, safe=False)
```

This currently throws

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `VenueSerialiser`.
```

If I replace the return line with

```
return Venue.objects.all()
```

I get a 200 but I need it in json

```
class VenueSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = ('name', 'location', 'capacity', 'photo_url', 'accomodation', 'cost', 'description', 'postcode', 'email', 'website')
```

Comment: why are you returning a JsonResponse in the get_queryset() method???? And it seems you're not using plain Django but django-rest-framework, (`ListAPIView`) which already returns JSON anyway. The `get_queryset()` method is supposed to return a queryset (or a list).

Comment: oh okay, sorry I was just following a tutorial. Do I need to create a separate function to return json?

Comment: your view is already returning json. You don't need to do anything. If you type the url to your view in a browser you'll see that the response **is** json.

Comment: when I run the code above I get the error - 
"AttributeError at /api/v1/venues/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `VenueSerialiser`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `bytes` instance.
Original exception text was: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'name'."

Comment: I've added my serialiser class too

Comment: you have to `return sorted_venues` in your method and remove all the lines after your comment `# print(sorted_venues)` because as I said you can't return a `JsonResponse` there.

Comment: what you return in `get_queryset()` **MUST** be a list of `Venue` objects. Otherwise the serializer won't be able to serialise it. So when you just `return Venue.objects.all()` it should work. As you said it returns a status 200 and in your browser you should see JSON. If it fails with your code for `sorted_venues`, you need to check that `sorted_venues` is a **list** and that each item in the list is a **Venue**.

Comment: yeah returning Venue.objects.all works fine. but I sorted the objects into a dictionary where the key is important. This is why I wanted to convert the diction of key:objects to json and return that way. returning sorted_venues fails

Comment: You should do all this in `get`, not `get_queryset`. You don't need a queryset, or a serializer, since you are not using them.

Comment: thank you so much! that is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to Daniel Roseman and dirkgroten I changed get_queryset to get and the json was returned. Thanks for the help :)